# How to read RSS feed http://picasaweb.google.com/ using c# net 2?

Tags: feed, picasa

How to read feed http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/base/user/... using c# net 2 ?

Comment: Did you try anything, or are you expecting us to do your research?

Comment: I find but only to read feeds generic and not for picasa

Comment: That's because RSS *is* generic and not Picasa specific. What problems do you have using RSS APIs for reading Picasa? If you describe this, we can help you and I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: thank you, but I work in remote hosting and can not install libraries RSS API's

Comment: You haven't said that in your question. You have provided way too little information for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you use the API to get this done?

https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/?csw=1

Comment: thank you but I work in remote hosting and can not install libraries